# using delay before an animation begins instead of queue a delay

Tags: jquery, html, delay

I would like to start an animation after 5 seconds (so not right when the page loads but a few more seconds after that)

i try using delay but it doesnt seem to work, where am i wrong? is there a way to create a timer for it to count down before it starts?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".info").delay(5000).css({marginLeft:'-999px'}).animate(
        {marginLeft: '0px'},{duration: 2000, queue:false});
    $(".jamey").css({left:'999px'}).animate(
        {left:'606px'},{duration:2000, queue: false});
    $(".jamey2").css({left:'999px'}).animate(
        {left:'606px'},{duration:2000, queue: false});
    $(".rip-date").css({left:'999px'}).animate(
        {left:'375px'}, {duration:2000, queue: false});
    $('#overlay').animate({ opacity: 1, }, 5000, function(){
            // done fading.
    });
    $(".info").css({color:'#191919'});
```

Comment: _.delay()_ adds a delay to the animation/effects queue of the elements you call it for, it doesn't pause your JS execution. So the code you show delays only the animation on the _".info"_ element not the others. Except that you have every animation including that one set to _queue : false,_ a setting that is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`delay` is generally better for adding a delay between animations. In this case, I would use a `setTimeout`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //Your code here...
    }, 5000); 
});
```

Comment: thank you very much! i knew something like this exist i just wasnt sure what it might be called.